# Why is the php command flush not working in Safari?

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, safari, flush

I have a time-consuming php script, so I'd like to give the user some feedback. Simplified it to get to the core problem. This script works perfectly fine in Firefox (flushing the output instantly), but Safari waits until all the content is generated. Why? And how could I fix that?

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
header('Content-Encoding: none;'); 
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$j = 8;
$k = pow(2, 10);

echo "One moment please...".str_pad('', $k)."<br />\n<br />\n";
flush();

$i = 0;
while ($i < $j) { 
    $i++;
    echo "Test ".$i.str_pad('',$k)."<br />\n";
    flush();
    sleep(1);
} 
?>
```

And by the way: Chrome won't load this page at all, it gives me `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`.

Furthermore I tried to put

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv no-gzip 1
</IfModule>
```

in .htaccess but no luck. Also tried `SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary`. Any clues how to get Safari (and Chrome) do the same as Firefox?

---

I read everything on php.net about `flush()`, `ob_flush()`, `ob_start()`, etc. and I read almost every question about flush + all comments on Stackoverflow from the past 20+ years.
I tried to add `ini_set('output_buffering', 'On');` or `ini_set('output_buffering', 'Off');`, added `ob_start(null, 4096);`, `ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');`, `header('Cache-Control: no-cache');`, `header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');` and/or `header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');`. I put `@ob_flush();` before or after my `flush();`, tried to raise the value in `str_pad` up to 2^16 (65,536) but nothing helped.
Unfortunately I don't seem to have any control over the Apache server at my hosting provider (which runs PHP 8.1 with FastCGI). Since it works on Firefox I must have done something right, I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
`ob_start("ob_gzhandler")` is intended to be used as a callback function for ob_start() to help facilitate sending gz-encoded data to web browsers that support compressed web pages. [source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php)

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
header('Content-Encoding: none;');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
$j = 8;
$k = pow(2, 10);

echo "One moment please...".str_pad('', $k)."<br />\n<br />\n";


$i = 0;
while ($i < $j) {
    $i++;
    echo "Test ".$i.str_pad('',$k)."<br />\n";
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
?>
```

Outputs (on Chrome):

> One moment please...
>
> Test 1 Test 2 Test 3 Test 4 Test 5 Test 6 Test 7 Test 8

Comment: Thanks. I tried that too but all browesrs then do the same: wait until all content is generated (after the 8 seconds) before showing it to the user. At least with `Content-encoding: none` it works as I was hoping in Firefox: showing each line immediately after each `sleep(1);`. Any more clues?

Comment: Found it!, code has been edited. it displayed for me instantly on chrome, try it 
Adding     ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
before everything will tell the content is compressed

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php

Comment: Note the code will take little bit to execute but it's giving the intended results hopefully

Comment: I really appreciate your thoughts. However, with adding `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");` it still displays everything at once instead of generating a line every second (at least on my iMac with Safari 16.4, Firefox 113.0 and Chrome 113.0.5672.92).

Comment: Did you modify the flush() to ob_flush() as well?

Comment: Sorry I missed that, yes I just did. Chrome and Firefox now do want I want (thanks!), but Safari still waits the 8 seconds until all content is generated before showing it to the user

Comment: Yes it has a little bit of delay, that's what the most I could get to sorry, and my Mac machine is in my office and it's midnight lol. I'll see if I can try making it faster on safari

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [hareth py](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14763977/hareth-py) I found the answer!

```
<?php 
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
header('Content-Encoding: none;');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8;');
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
$j = 200;
$k = pow(2, 10);

echo "One moment please...".str_pad('', $k)."<br />\n<br />\n";


$i = 0;
while ($i < $j) {
    $i++;
    echo "Test ".$i.str_pad('',$k)."<br />\n";
    ob_flush();
    usleep(100000);
} 
?>
```

I raised $j to 200 and lowered the sleep to 0.1 second. Safari is indeed a little slow to respond, but it will display line by line eventually. Just like Firefox and Chrome.